# Яндекс карты API расстояния

Tags: api, яндекс-карты

Есть у Яндекс карт(может и других) вот такое синее окошко в котором указано расстояние до ближайшего поворота, когда уже по маршруту двигаешься.
А можно ли достать из карт только эту часть и передать куда то?
Куда копать, где посмотреть?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вставить такую информацию куда либо, кроме карты Яндекс на публичной веб-странице, вам потребуется [коммерческая лицензия](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/jsapi-geocoder.html#jsapi-geocoder__standart) API Яндекс Карт.

К самой же информации (к сегментам пути) вы можете получить доступ в JS API. [Пример есть в песочнице Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/router).